# Which is the difference between logger level and threshold filter level in Logback?

Tags: logging, logback

I have an appender with a `ThreshholdFilter` with level INFO:

```
<appender name="my_apender" class="com.my.apender.MyAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
</appender>
```

and a logger with level INFO, too:

```
<logger name="whatever" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="my_appender"/>
</logger>
```

Which is the difference between both levels?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The level assigned for the logger is the one used by your logger, whereas the level assigned inside the filter  `ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter` is the level from which this appender will be logging stuff, for more [details](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html).

Here is an example to clarify things :

```xml
<!-- deny all events with a level below INFO, that is TRACE and DEBUG -->
<appender name="my_apender1" class="com.my.apender.MyAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
</appender>

<!-- deny all events with a level below DEBUG, that is TRACE-->
<appender name="my_apender2" class="com.my.apender.MyAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>DEBUG</level>
    </filter>
</appender>

<!-- event with level DEBUG will be handled only by my_apender2, and events with higher levels than DEBUG will be handled by both appenders -->
<logger name="whatever" level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="my_appender1"/>
    <appender-ref ref="my_appender2"/>
</logger>
```

Answer (score 2):

To make the distinction clear, lets take an example...
...Lets say your logger is associated with two appenders, one appender logging to myapp_all.log file and another logging to myapp_error.log. Now if you want log only ERROR level logs to the myapp_error.log, you would use an appender filter as opposed to logger filter. Since a single class is generally associated with a single logger, you cannot bifurcate the ERROR level flow using a logger level.

Answer (score 0):

Logger's level is a level of events that will be passed from it.
Appender's threshold filter is a level of events that finally comes to the target destination (console, file, etc).